# can I split UI (xml) section of one fragment to many (android)

Tags: android, xml, split, fragment, tablelayout

I have one fragment which contains 5 tableslayout
if i want to declare all tables in xml file, it became 200 line code for example
is there any way to declare each table in a separate xml file ,then include all of them in main layout ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe consider the `<include/>` tag? More info here: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html